# Call AllowAnonymous method in AuthorizationRequired class gives me 302 error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a method in my AccountController, which is a AuthorizationRequired class. But when method is called, the user is not yet authorized. So I have written the method like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Accept()
    {
        string memberno = TempData["memberno"] as string;
        _accountRepository.AcceptTerms(memberno);
        Account acc = _accountRepository.GetAccount(memberno);
        LoginViewModel loginView = new LoginViewModel
        {
            MemberNo = acc.AccountNo,
            Password = acc.Password,
            ForgotPassword = false,
            RememberMe = false
        };
        return Login(loginView,"");
    }
```

And my method which calls it is a `$.ajax` method:

```
    function acceptTermses() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Accept", "Account")',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (da) {
            alert("did it");
        }, error: function (w) {
            alert("FAILED");
        }
    });
}
```

But when I try to call the method, I get this in the browser:

```
Remote Address:::1:33405
Request URL:http://localhost:33405/Account/Accept
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
```

and

```
Failed to load repsonse data
```

Instead of failing my method, it does this call instead, after the 302 Found call:

```
http://localhost:33405/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FAccept
```

And then it runs with "success", but never calls the controller method.

I have tried to do the same call to another method in the class, and that worked just fine. I have no idea why it wont run with this method.

Comment: Have you got any security rules configured in `Web.config`?

Comment: this is because you are using return Login(loginView,""); ie redirecting to Login Action which is wrong

Comment: Even if I am using it as returning null, it will never call the method.
And no, @DominicZukiewicz , there is no security rules set yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `return Login(loginView,"")` i.e. redirecting to `Login` `Action` which is wrong in your question.

Try This :-

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Accept()
{
    string memberno = TempData["memberno"] as string;
    _accountRepository.AcceptTerms(memberno);
    Account acc = _accountRepository.GetAccount(memberno);
    LoginViewModel loginView = new LoginViewModel
    {
        MemberNo = acc.AccountNo,
        Password = acc.Password,
        ForgotPassword = false,
        RememberMe = false
    };
    return Json({ message="success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}

function acceptTermses() {

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Accept", "Account")',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype:'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.message=="success"){
        window.location.href="/Account/Login";
       }
    }, error: function (w) {
        alert("FAILED");
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Exactly. If I knew why, I was not in this situation ☺

Comment: @MothCreek...just use exactly this controller and ajax call see in console and tell what console is saying???